# React Native: How to stretch TouchableOpacity

Tags: react-native

I am trying to have two large buttons (TouchableOpacity) be next to each other and take up 50% of the width of the screen.

But they only seem to be as wide as the Text component within them.

[image]

How can I make the two TouchableOpacity take up the full width of the screen, with each taking up 50% of the width?

```
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
      height: 200,
      justifyContent: 'space-around',
    },
    btn: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      padding: 20,
      borderWidth: 1,
    },
  });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn}>
        <Text>Left</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn}>
        <Text>Right</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a width of 50% to your btn class

```
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
      height: 200,
      justifyContent: 'space-around',
    },
    btn: {
      width: '50%',
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      padding: 20,
      borderWidth: 1,
    },
  });
```

You can also use [dimensions](https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions) from react native and put **width: windowWidth/2** on your btn class.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use react native's `Dimensions`

https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions

```
  import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

  const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
      height: 200,
      justifyContent: 'space-around',
    },
    btn: {
      width: width*0.5,
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      padding: 20,
      borderWidth: 1,
    },   
  });
```

Comment: This worked thank you. (I ended up using `useWindowDimensions()` as recommended in the link.) Although I feel as if this should have been possible without having to measure the width, and simply use CSS.